# String comparison; finding 'like' characters

Tags: php

I am doing a quick duplicate check on a form. When comparing two strings, I was trying something like this:

```
if (stripos($_SESSION['website'], $f['website']))
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: stripos() in...
```

I do not want it to be an exact match, basically if the `$_SESSION['website']` is www.google.com, I'd want `stripos` to return `true` if `$f['website]` is www.goog.com

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

edit: I was doing some testing, and noticed if my `$_SESSION['website']` variable contains `www` and `.com`. As does my `$f['website]` variable. shouldn't `strpos` return that as true?

Comment: `stripos()` was introduced in PHP5. What version are you running? Alternativly, you can make a copy of the string, use `strtolower()` to ensure everything is lowercase, use `strpos()` to find the position of the search-term and apply that to the original string.

Comment: You've got two different questions here. The first is the fatal error, which looks like @MikeB has figured out. The second is that you want to do something much more complex than the `stripos` function alone can handle. The [documentation for stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) says "Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string." So `stripos` would return **0** (not true) if `$f['website']` is 'www.goog', but it would return false for www.goog.com.

Comment: @MikeB , I am running PHP5, but your `strtolower()` method will work for now. Thanks! @Travesty3, do you have any other suggestions on how I may able to do a string comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[stripos()](http://nl.php.net/stripos), as per the manual only exists in the core of PHP 5 or later. If stripos doesn't exist, that would suggest you're using PHP 4, which is wildly outdated. I suggest you upgrade. If for some insane reason you really can't, you can always force the two strings to lowercase before calling strpos, which would have the same effect:

```
<?php
// PHP 5.
$pos = stripos( 'www.google.com', 'google.com' );

// PHP 4.
$pos = strpos( strtolower( 'www.google.com' ), strtolower( 'google.com' ) );
```

That said, there's something more to your code: you're checking `if( stripos( $foo, $bar ) )` which would return 0 if the string `$foo` starts with the string `$bar`. You should check with `if( stripos( $foo, $bar ) !== false )` instead.

On another note: I don't think stripos will help you. You mentioned `www.google.com` and `www.goog.com`, which are two totally different things. The latter is not a substring of the former, and stripos checks for the starting position of a substring, it doesn't do "loose comparison".

If you want "like" and you have the terms in an array, you might want to check out the [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function which will give you an indication of how similar two different strings are. As an example:

```
<?php
$similarity = 0;
similar_text( 'www.goog.com', 'www.google.com', $similarity );
var_dump( $similarity );
```

The above code would set `$similarity` to `float(92.307692307692)`, which is the similarity of the two strings in percentages. You can decide the threshold for the similarity yourself, naturally.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the `similar_text` function. I would have thought doing something like this would take much more work.

Answer (score -2):

its a strpos('Your String Or Websitename','The Term Search');

if its find the match it returns true otherwise it returns false

```
$a=strpos($_SESSION['website'], $f['website'])
```

if($a==TRUE)
   {

```
    //do stuff
```

}
   else 
    {

```
    //other stuff
}
```